# How to migrate "MapSpaFallbackRoute" from .net core 2.x to 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, migration

I can't figure out how to migrate some code syntactically from .net core 2.x to 3.1.

More specific this piece of code:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
    name: "spa-fallback",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

I think the default route is solved but I cant figure out how to do the "routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute" in 3.1.

This is my current code in 3.1 where I'm still missing the fallback route. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```